# NSButton rotate animation clockwise in cocoa mac application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, nsbutton

I am having a cocoa mac application in objective c.

When I press my NSButton, I want to rotate it clockwise with animation for some seconds.

I tried below code but not working.

```
CABasicAnimation *ani = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    ani.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    ani.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-M_PI*2];
    [btnScan.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
    ani.duration = 2.0; // seconds
    ani.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
    [btnScan.layer addAnimation:ani forKey:nil];
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find a proper solution for this.

Can anyone help me on this, please?

Comment: -M_PI*2 is basically a zero angle rotation. Have you tried M_PI just to see if your code is working properly?

Comment: Yes, nothing seems to work if I change that also...

Comment: For others having problems with the view orbiting like crazy instead of spinning around it's axis, also do **view.layer.position = view.center;** (center here is precalculated, NSView is incapable of doing anything useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[btnScan setWantsLayer:YES];` before you do your animation. NSView unlike UIView doesn't have a backing layer by default.

from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW12):

> In iOS apps, Core Animation is always enabled and every view is backed
>   by a layer. In OS X, apps must explicitly enable Core Animation
>   support by doing the following:
>
> - Link against the QuartzCore framework. (iOS apps must link against this framework only if they use Core Animation interfaces explicitly.)
> - Enable layer support for one or more of your NSView objects by doing one of the following:
>
>   - In your nib files, use the View Effects inspector to enable layer support for your views. The inspector displays checkboxes for the
>       selected view and its subviews. It is recommended that you enable
>       layer support in the content view of your window whenever possible.
>   - For views you create programmatically, call the view’s setWantsLayer: method and pass a value of YES to indicate that the
>       view should use layers.

Comment: Thanks so much for this... but one more thing to add. Can slight more animation be added with some code in the above. Thanks...

Comment: @Manthan please explain more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please have a look at this app https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sync.me-social-caller-id-for/id340787494?mt=8. If you press sync me, it animates.

Comment: @Manthan this seems like a separate question, lets keep it all relevant. If you want to achieve specific animation you probably would have to ask for ideas in a new thread.